# Photoshop: Quick Select Acting wierd

Tags: adobe-photoshop, toolbar

sorry not sure if this post belongs here but this tool started acting pretty wierd lately.

the selection goes out of the clicked area of same color even though its too obvious that it shouldn't. it does so even on a simple 2d image.

alt-clicking is even wierder.

1. it only deselects the clicked area
2. the memory usage skyrockets immediately
3. the loading bar appears which takes almost 1-2 secs everytime.

This started to happen 2 days ago only before that it worked perfectly. Why?

I use ver 2015.5.

Comment: First thing I would try is to [reset](http://www.pixeltraining.net/blog/2011/03/how-to-reset-a-tool.html) the tool. If resetting doesn't change the tool's behavior, take a look at [this](http://asktimgrey.com/2015/05/18/quick-selection-is-slow/)